# Adding unique key/index to table and its influence on existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, unique-key

I have a table that was doing fine with no unique keys so far. This table is working fine but the code of inserting/updating/deleting procedures is getting a bit unreadable since conditions to recognize a correct entry in table are getting longer and longer, so I started to consider adding a new column with an unique ID to it.

There are already answered questions about adding a unique identity to table on SO, but I was wondering if it can have any negative impact on currectly existing records. The table itself isn't big, it never has more than a few thousands of entries, but it's used and updated often and it wouldn't be easy to stop using it for more than a moment. So is there anything I should be aware of that could mess up the data or can I just happily add a column with unique identity and everything will work just fine? Can there be any problems with currently existing stored procedures, especially the ones altering the records? To be honest I can't think of anything but I'd rather be sure since I'm far from being experienced in SQL and databases.

Same for adding indexes to an already existing table - I imagine there would be some shifting around involved, so is there any negative impact on the records?

If you need examples of the procedures I mentioned, just think of simple insert/delete/update statements with needlessly long where clauses. No joins with other tables, no multiple transactions within a single procedure.

Comment: If you don't already have *some* form of key for the data, adding a new one won't help at all with the lack of data quality - if you're not enforcing keys currently, there's nothing to stop you having two (or more) rows containing exactly the same values in every column. Adding a new column to uniquely identify these rows doesn't resolve the fact that you've still got duplicates in the data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right in terms of quality, but I was thinking about this change from the SPs' readability point of view as well as managing data on the side of the application using the database. Currently if I want to e.g. update a record, I need to pass a needlessly large amount of data as parameters just to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current data will not be affected by adding columns or changing indexes.

But code might be affected.

1. `SELECT *` will now return more columns.
2. The column order might change depending on where you add the column.
3. Someone might `INSERT` without a column list. That will now fail.
4. Performance might become slightly worse. If your app relies on very strict performance standards that might be a problem. I consider this to be unlikely.

I'm sure there are others but these are the ones that I can think of right now.

Comment: Why adding an unique key might be a problem in terms of performance? I thought that it might be actually faster after adding the ID if most of long where clauses are gone from inserts/updates etc.

Comment: If you modify your queries to take advantage of them, that is likely to help, yes. You're likely to realize some gains. My comment was for the case that you just add the column and change nothing else. I thought you were concerned with how existing code behaves under the changes.